# Can't read .exe file in C properly

Tags: c

I tried to print out the raw data of an PE file with this C application:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    if (argc != 2) 
    {printf("Syntax: <file>\n"); 
    return 0;
    }
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Open file failed.\n");
        return 0; 
    }
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    unsigned char *string = (unsigned char*)malloc(fsize + 1);
    fread(string, fsize, 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    string[fsize] = 0;
    printf("File content:\n ");  
    printf("%s", string); 
    return 0;}
```

I compiled it with MinGw gcc:

```
foo.c -o foo.exe -m32
```

If I pass a text file to `foo.exe` it prints out the content of that file, but if I try to print out the raw data of an .exe it only gives me the first 3 bytes: MZE. 
I thought it has something to do with `fseek()`, it may not find the proper EOF, but after I used the winapi ReadFile to read the file, I got the same results. I know it most likely a stupid mistake, so how to print out the whole file?

Comment: Per **7.21.9.2** of the C standard:  A binary stream need not
meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a whence value of `SEEK_END`.  (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)  I wish I knew where using `fseek()/ftell()` to get the size of a file comes from.  It's wrong.  It only works in a strict POSIX environment, and in POSIX you can just use `stat()` to get the size of a file.  For just one example where it's wrong, see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB27U_6.2.0/com.ibm.zos.r12.cbcpx01/ossbin.htm%23ossbin

Comment: And per **7.21.3**:  Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has **undefined behavior** for a binary stream (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream
with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial shift state.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, it gave me the proper file size, but I will keep this in mind for the future, I think I will replace ftell with GetFileSize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities. Among them is the fact that the `%s` formating is for strings. A string is a sequence of non-0-characters, followed by a 0-character.

A binary file can have a 0 character at any position, perhaps at position 4, effectively cutting the string after the 3rd character.

Comment: Actually, I think there is only one possibility: That it encounters a zero that it interprets as the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something stupid. I was able to print out the .exe file char by char  by iterating through the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` prints text, not binary data. I have no idea what sort of output you were expecting, but that's not going to work. For starters, binary data contains zero values, which are interpreted as the end of the string in C.

Binary data also can contain newlines, other characters that have special meaning along with garbage characters that will mean nothing when printed to the screen.